# Issue in urlencoding using MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have a few textfiles which are input for a MySQL database. These textfiles contain characters like é and ë. I have struggled getting the data properly into the database and now it seems I've finally got it right. However, I would like to know if there is a better way to do this than the way I describe here.

1. The textfiles are all UTF-8 encoded.
2. The PHP scripts are all UTF-8 encoded as well. I've read that this is very important.
3. All HTML output is done using a header like this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
4. The MySQL database is created using a collation of latin1_swedish_ci (the character set is left blank)
5. All the columns that contain characters (VARCHAR) are defined using a collation of latin1_swedish_ci

I assume the right way to store url encoded strings is when I see the character é stored as %C3%A9 in the database. I found a MySQL function for urlencoding [here](http://jeremythomerson.com/2013/05/30/urlencoder-function-for-mysql/).
But when I open up phpMyAdmin I see the character é is presented as %C3%A3%C2%A9.

I can add another statement to replace characters in the database, but something tells me there is a more efficient way to achieve this.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `urlencode` and `urldecode` for generating links, not for data storage. Update your database to use UTF8 as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Could you please add the source code where you read the source textfile, convert (urlencode) and the SQL of insertion ? I'd say to use `ascii_bin` as character set collation in mysql but i may be wrong

Comment: The question indicated by chris85 was really helpful. I got it all working now! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is missing from your list of 5 things is

6. I tell mysql that the client bytes are utf8-encoded.  I do this via `$mysqli_obj->set_charset('utf8');` or `new PDO('dblib:host=host;dbname=db;charset=UTF8', $user, $pwd);` or `SET NAMES utf8`.  (or utf8mb4).

The client sees utf8, the table sees latin1; the conversion will occur when `INSERTing` and `SELECTing`, but it needs #6 to know to do so.

Comment: Note that `é` and `ë` are both available in latin1.

Comment: I finally got it all working. Turned out I used a wrong charset in an HTML-file. Thanks for your input!